# Can not create system object in VBA

Tags: .net, vba, vb.net

In a VBA macro,
the below System Objects can not be created,
while other objects can create, like "WScript.Shell" and "ADODB.Connection"

I assume that might related to .NET envirionment problem,
.Net framework 4.7.2 is installed, confirmed in reg Editer, but can not be found in control panel.

There is no .NET core runtime or SDK is installed.
Since the machine is customer environment, I can not install SDK to try.
[image]
Is there anyone has met this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This Object needs to have .Net framework 3.5 installed - without it will not work.

Comment: `UTF8Encoding` should be [available in 4.7.2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thank you, I was checking it too.
But, the .net framework 4.7.2 seems to be installed in reg, however in control panel can not find it. 
It's probably the .net framework 4.7.2 not be installed properly。。。

Comment: Which is this, VBA or .NET VB?  It's clearly not both.

Comment: It's VBA. 
I tried to get .net core sdk installed, (dotnet --info) should .net is installed properly.
But the problem still...
is that caused by Excel itself? or some configuration problem?